# Formatting your code

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm working on this project with code that is really impossible to read simply because it is formatted so bad.

I've tried to format the code with plugins and built-in functionality in VIM, Netbeans, Sublime Text 2 and Eclipse.

They just make the code worse... Any other suggestions?

We're talking PHP, HTML, Smarty (templates) and Javascript.

Thanks.

Comment: when you downvote, please leave a comment why :)

Comment: I dint downvote but guess it must be because this question doesn't belong here.! Probably on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: So many sites it's sometimes hard to know which goes where :)

Comment: Totally Agreed..!! They should come up with some smart AI where you post question at one site and it will forward it to proper place. :)

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the formatting done by the tools you mention such as ST2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also look for <yourlanguagename> Beautifier

e.g.

- [Javascript Beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/)
- [PHP Beautifier](http://beta.phpformatter.com/)
  ...

Answer (score 0):

I've had good results with PHPStorm, might wanna try that one. It's a very decent IDE as well.